# How to say, "try to __", "have to __"

Tags: translation

For some reason I can't remember how to say "try to **_" or "have to (must) _**" in Japanese. How can I say this?  Any variations you can include would be appreciated.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Try to ~

> ~ようとする (Does not give any information whether the action was actually carried out in entirety)
>
> ~てみる (Try for the sake of seeing the result, does **not** have negative implication as in "to try (unsuccessfully )" )

---

have to(must) ~

> ~なければならない
>
> ~なくては｛ならない・いけない｝
>
> ~ないといけない
>
> ~ねばならない

~なくては　is often contracted to ~なくちゃ

~なければならない can also be contracted and have ならない elided to form "~なけりゃ" or "~なきゃ" which is used informally.

Comment: also ～ないとだめ, much like ～ないといけない

Comment: I was under the assumption that ~ようとする meant more that "I have the urge or volition to ~" and implies more of a feeling or motivation to do something "I'm feeling motivated to study" 勉強しようとする

Comment: `〜なきゃ` (as mentioned) as well as `〜なくては` and `〜ないと` are often said with the "ending" implied.

Comment: Doesn't ～はず　or ～べき　count as should or must?

Comment: @dotnetN00b I don't think ~はず　counts. This is because "should" in English has two uses. 1. probabilistic reasoning e.g. "The train *should* be arriving in 5 minutes.". 2. indication of obligation or duty (ought to do~) e.g. "I *should* be going home now.". ~はず does not indicate obligation or duty; it indicates the expectation of the speaker. ~べき on the other hand indicates obligation or duty. Both are "should" but neither are "must".

Comment: I think it's actually really hard to compare English and Japanese modal expressions in the first place because *every* English modal auxiliary can express at least two kinds of modality, while most Japanese modal expressions can only express one.  *Should*, *must*, and *ought* can all express both types of meaning you list, so it's hard to compare はず or べき to any of them directly.

Answer (score 3):

- try to: `...-te みる`
- have to: `...-(a)nak-ere ba ならない`

> 食べてみる
> 'try to eat'
>
> 食べなければならない
> 'have to eat'

Answer (score 3):

Some other grammar for "have to" that was not yet mentioned:

#### 〜ことになる

This means "it has been decided that 〜", but is often used as an indirect way to say that you have to do something (even if it's been decided by you).

> - 家族が大阪に引っ越すことになった　→　It's been decided that my family is moving to Osaka (= We have to move there).

### More Advanced:

#### 〜ないわけにはいかない

#### 〜ざるをえない

#### 〜ないではいられない・〜ずにはいられない

These all basically mean "can't not do 〜" or "can't avoid doing 〜", although the double-negative may slightly lessen the "activeness" of having to do it.

> - この[推理小説]{すい・り・しょう・せつ}を終わりまで読まないではいられません。　→　"I have to / I can't not read this suspense novel all the way to the end!"

Each one has its nuances of what types of situations in which it can be used, whereas the "basic" ones in @Flaw's answers aren't limited (much, if at all).

### "Most Advanced" (mostly formal and/or written forms only.  Not likely used in conversation)

#### 〜ないではすまない・〜ずにはすまない

#### 〜ないではおかない・〜ずにはおかない

#### 〜を禁【きん】じ得【え】ない

#### 〜を余儀【よぎ】なくされる

Comment: Hmm, why aren't the heading hashes {#} parsing the furigana tags??

Answer (score 3):

It come to top of my mind for 'try to'
...してみる. やってみる....しようとする.
...を試みる.

and
...ねばならない.
...せざるを得ない.
...を余儀なくされる.
for 'have to.' But the last one may sound a bit antiquated today.