# What is the Japanese for "I'll check it out, I will try and see"?

Tags: set-phrases

I found a form using `見て`, and it seemed very useful, but I could never remember it. It means something like "I will try it out" or "I will try and see", and the Japanese form is something like `自転車見て...` I know this is vague, but I am also some form like this is pretty common and I can't remember what it is. Can anyone recall?

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to say, "try to __", "have to __"](http://japanese.stackexchange.com/questions/3593/how-to-say-try-to-have-to)

Comment: Not entirely sure if this is a duplicate of the "try to..." question. Are you thinking of "見てみる" (which is just a particular instance of Sawa's answer)? as in "見てみよう"/"見てみましょう"...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`てみる` is "try out ...".

> 自転車に乗ってみる
>   'try riding a bicycle'