# Cohortative ましょう with and without the auxiliary construction ～てみる

Tags: grammar, meaning, subsidiary-verbs

In "何かしてみましょう。" meaning "Let's try/do something.", what is the literal translation of "してみましょう"? I've got "して" means "doing" and "みましょう" means "let's watch or let's?".

How is "してみましょう" different from using "しましょう"? Would using "してましょう" be grammatically correct and mean the same thing?

Comment: I have taken the liberty of editing your question title to make it specific to the problem you are facing. Your question is a valid question but your original title was too vague. Do take a look at the meta post ["What are the attributes of a good question"](http://meta.japanese.stackexchange.com/q/732/542). These guidelines help to make your question more community friendly so that you may receive useful answers.

Comment: Related: http://japanese.stackexchange.com/questions/3593/how-to-say-try-to-have-to

Comment: "してましょう ... that can't be correct. Right?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

The form `〜てみます（みる）` means "to do something and see how it turns out/how it goes".  So `〜てみましょう` means "let's do it and see how it goes", whereas `〜ましょう` just means "let's do it".

> 何かしてみましょう　→　Let's do something and see what happens/how it turns out
>   何かしましょう　→　Let's do something

In this case, there's not a huge difference in the meaning (assuming this is said in a familiar context).  Using `〜てみましょう` simply adds a nuance of uncertainty regarding how it will be.